# codeigniter .cgi files

Tags: php, codeigniter, cgi

I want to utilize a .cgi file in a function call within my model:

```
function execute_shell_command($userID,$clientname){

  $shell_script_to_execute="jobscript.cgi";
  $jobtype="clientjob";

  echo shell_exec("bash '".$shell_script_to_execute."' '".$jobtype."' '".$userID."' '".$clientname."' '".$this->job_command."' '".$this->job_id."' '".$this->servername."'  '".$this->rootaccess."'  ");

}
```

How do  I load this cgi file, right now I don't know where to put it. In my assets folder?  Just looking for a good way to do it in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File paths in codeigniter are always relative to `index.php` so if your cgi-bin directory is sitting at the same level as your `index.php`

```
$shell_script_to_execute = "./cgi-bin/jobscript.cgi";
```

should work...